# Inner HTML with input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input, innerhtml

have a brief question regarding innerHTML and input values that have been entered. See the brief example below (using jQuery for convenience):

http://jsfiddle.net/F7urT/2/

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.send').click(function() {
        alert( $('.content').html() );
        return false;
    });
});​
```

**html:**

```
<div class="content">
    <input type="text" name="input" value="Old Value" />
    <input type="button" class="send" value="Send" />
</div>​
```

If you edit the input value, then click the 'Send' button, the alert shows that the innerHTML gotten contains the input with the "Old Value", rather than the value the user has entered. Why is this? And how can we get the HTML as a string with user entered input values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The new value is stored as a property not an attribute, the value can be obtained by `inputelement.value`, modifying the value does not affect the attribute. If you want the html with the new value just set the attribute to the new value.

For check boxes and radio buttons set the checked attribute, set the innerHTML for text areas, for selects set the selected attribute on the option

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/F7urT/5/

Comment: Thanks, simple but for one reason or another hadn't occurred to me. What about other kinds of form fields; select boxes, textareas, etc? Question should mentioned this rather than strictly inputs; my apologies.

Comment: Thanks. Very simple, and really should have copped this myself. Stubbornness lead me to waste time trying to figure out what was going on with InnerHTML, rather than implementing a simple solution. Thanks again. Believed that it actually got the current HTML, including any changed input values, etc, rather than literally reading the source.

Answer (score 5):

this solution is better. works for more inputs.

```
  $('input[type=text]').attr('value', function (i, val) { return val; });
  $('input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]').attr('checked', function () { return this.checked; });
  $('textarea').html(function () { return this.value; });
  $('select').find(':selected').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 4):

`$('#input_id').attr('value',$('#input_id').val());`
 will put the value into the html

Answer (score 3):

You can't get it with `.innerHTML` (`.html()`). Writing into an  element doesn't modify the html markup, nor will it change the `value` attribute in actual markup.

You can only access the current content by directly asking the  element for its `.value` - value. Using jQuery, you can do that via `.val()` too.

Answer (score 0):

DanCZ & Musa solutions works pretty good, but I had trouble with the textarea.

I have to implement this in a Typescript project and the only way I've found to make the textarea show the value is this :

```
textarea.innerHTML = textarea.value;
```